# ORA-12015 materialized view complex query error with simple join two table

Tags: oracle, join, materialized-view

I have 2 simple table which has columns like :

table1 :

- "OBJECTID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE
- "OLCEK_ID" NUMBER(*,0)

table2 :

- "OBJECTID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE

i created materialized log view as below :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table1 
  WITH ROWID(OBJECTID,olcek_id), SEQUENCE 
  INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table2 
  WITH ROWID(OBJECTID), SEQUENCE 
  INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

And when creating materialized view i got an error :  **ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query.**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "PUBLIC"."TEST_MV"
  REFRESH FAST 
  AS SELECT a.OLCEK_ID 
  FROM TABLE1  a join TABLE2 ko ON a.OLCEK_ID= ko.OBJECTID;
```

I'm struggling to understand which part of my view is complex. Offical docs have example with joins.

Answer (score 2):

[5.2.2 About Materialized Views Containing Only Joins](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-3B903558-0C98-4033-9BCD-4A146220E868)

> If you specify REFRESH FAST, Oracle Database performs further
> verification of the query definition to ensure that fast refresh can
> be performed if any of the detail tables change. These additional
> checks are:
>
> - A materialized view log must be present for each detail table unless the table supports partition change tracking (PCT). Also, when a
>   materialized view log is required, the ROWID column must be present in
>   each materialized view log.
> - **The rowids of all the detail tables must appear in the SELECT list of the materialized view query definition.**

```
create table table1(
"OBJECTID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
"OLCEK_ID" NUMBER(*,0));

create table table2(
"OBJECTID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table1 
  WITH ROWID(OBJECTID,olcek_id), SEQUENCE 
  INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON table2 
  WITH ROWID(OBJECTID), SEQUENCE 
  INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

Then:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "TEST_MV"
  REFRESH FAST as
SELECT a.OLCEK_ID, a.rowid as t1r, ko.rowid as t2r
FROM table1 a join table2 ko ON a.OLCEK_ID= ko.OBJECTID;

Materialized view created.

SQL>
```